# C++ Program Compiles in Windows and Linux. But Doesn't Work on Linux

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, initialization, posix

I think it might be something related to the way my pointers are used/initialized in my struct, but I'm not completely sure. I use 'g++ -lpthread main.cpp' to compile. The program just hangs in Linux, while executing properly in windows. The program doesn't even spit out a cout I put in the beginning of the code for debugging purposes.

```
#include "pthread.h"
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "time_functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


struct vars {
    char buffer[10][1000];
    int put;
    int take;
    sem_t openSlot;
    sem_t slotInactive;
    sem_t newData;
    ifstream readFile;
    ofstream writeFile;

};

void *write(void *in) //consumer, writes data to file and deletes data from buffer
{
    vars* writeVars = (vars*)in;
    while (true)
    {
        sem_wait(&(*writeVars).newData);
        sem_wait(&(*writeVars).slotInactive);
        if ((*writeVars).buffer[(*writeVars).take % 10][0] != '$')
        {
            (*writeVars).writeFile << (*writeVars).buffer[(*writeVars).take % 10];
            if ((*writeVars).readFile.eof() != true)
            {
                (*writeVars).writeFile << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        (*writeVars).take++;
        sem_post(&(*writeVars).openSlot);
        sem_post(&(*writeVars).slotInactive);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

void *read(void *in) //producer, reads data into buffer
{
    vars* readVars = (vars*)in;
    char read_line[1000];
    while ((*readVars).readFile.getline(read_line, 1000))
    {
        sem_wait(&(*readVars).openSlot);
        sem_wait(&(*readVars).slotInactive);
        strcpy((*readVars).buffer[(*readVars).put % 10], read_line);
        (*readVars).put++;
        sem_post(&(*readVars).slotInactive);
        sem_post(&(*readVars).newData);
    }
    sem_wait(&(*readVars).openSlot);
    sem_wait(&(*readVars).slotInactive);
    (*readVars).buffer[(*readVars).put % 10][0] = '$';
    sem_post(&(*readVars).slotInactive);
    sem_post(&(*readVars).newData);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char pause[10];

    vars *varsPointer, var;
    varsPointer = &var;

    var.take = 0;
    var.put = 0;

    var.writeFile.open(argv[2], ios::out);
    var.readFile.open(argv[1], ios::in);

    start_timing();
    sem_init(&var.openSlot, 0, 10); 
    sem_init(&var.slotInactive, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&var.newData, 0, 0);

    pthread_t read_Thread, write_Thread;

    pthread_create(&read_Thread, NULL, read, varsPointer);
    pthread_create(&write_Thread, NULL, write, varsPointer);

    pthread_join(read_Thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(write_Thread, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&var.openSlot);
    sem_destroy(&var.slotInactive);
    sem_destroy(&var.newData);

    stop_timing();

    var.readFile.close();
    var.writeFile.close();

    //Display timer
    cout << "wall clock time (ms):" << get_wall_clock_diff() * 1000 << '\n';
    cout << "cpu time (ms):" << get_CPU_time_diff() * 1000 << '\n';
    cout << "Type Something and Press Enter To Continue";

    cin >> pause; //Just used to keep cmd promt open in Windows after program execution

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you return `void*`?

Comment: @PaoloM returns void* because that's what pthread expects.

Comment: I removed the return 0; in both the void* functions, compiled fine, but still the same issue. Doesn't execute.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info for C++, e.g. with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). You really should use C++11 things like lambdas & containers.

Comment: You need to `cout << endl` or otherwise flush the buffer to consistently see output on the console.

Comment: I wanted to point out that `(*p).member` is weird syntax for C and C++. That is why both languages have a `->` operator so that you can write `p->member`.

Comment: Also, we can't compile your example because it is missing a lot of code. Why not trim it down until it has only the parts that break, all in one file?

Comment: Oh the only code that I didn't include is the time_functions.h file. only 2 functions that access it are called in the main (start_timing, and stop_timing).